# Pointer in typedef struct

Tags: c

I came across a stack tutorial in the C language and I can't seem to understand what the `*Stack` pointer is pointing towards nor the `*next` pointer.
I would just like to have a quick explanation on what these two pointers actually point to.

```
typedef struct StackElement
    {
        int value;
        struct StackElement *next;
    }StackElement, *Stack;
```

Comment: in general, it is a poor programming practice to hide a pointer in a typedef.  I.E.  the `*stack` will create problems with humans reading the code.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither points to anything in the example you've given. This code is just the declaration of the structure type itself. You could break the typedefs out into maybe simpler form:

```
struct StackElement
{
    int value;
    struct StackElement *next;
};

typedef struct StackElement StackElement;
typedef struct StackElement *Stack;
```

That is, there is a declaration of the structure itself, which contains a field `next` to be used by the implementation code of this stack. That field, when filled in, will point to another `struct StackElement` structure.

The `typedef` parts just make convenience names - `StackElement` can be used in place of `struct StackElement`, and `Stack` can be used instead of `struct StackElement *`.

Comment: Now I got it ! Thanks